# AVS video decoder DirectShow filter or MFT

Tags: video, directshow, ms-media-foundation, avs

Does anybody know about AVS-format video decoder DS filter or Media Foundation transform?
I tried to search the web for it but couldn't find...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard of this codec before. Sounds interesting. As the [wiki page for this codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Standard) said, libavcodec and ffmpeg have a decoder for this included. Because these are the base for ffdshow and lavfilters, maybe there will be an implementation soon. The only current decoder for directshow I could find is this one: [AVSShow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avsdshow/). I don't know if this works, havn't tested it.

There also exists an [Decoder SDK](http://www.avs.org.cn/fruits/en/softList.asp), but I couldn't read the chines to download it. With a little experience someone can implement a Decoder (filter/DMO/MFT) with this.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, in the upper-left corner of the Chinese site you have the option to get the content in English. And I wasn't aware of AVSShow, thanks!